# Recently I'm having CORS problems only in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, request, cors

Having some major CORS problems with Google Chrome lately:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin '...' has been blocked
>   by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access
>   control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

The weird thing is that the request works perfectly on Mozilla Firefox.

I tried to add different headers to the server including:


**Access-Control-Allow-Headers**: Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Accept,Access-Control-Request-Method,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Headers

**Access-Control-Allow-Methods**: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT,OPTIONS,HEAD

**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**: *


Also **before** the "CORS Block" there's an OPTIONS request method Google Chrome sends my server but here i get a 500 server error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 4 exceptions. 
>   They are:
>
> 1. javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error creating a JAXBContext for wadl processing.
> 2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on
>      org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlApplicationContextImpl
> 3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of
>      org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor$OptionsHandler
>      errors were found
> 4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on
>      org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor$OptionsHandler
>
>    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
>      org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
>      org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
>      org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
>      org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
>      org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>      com.isyndix.rest.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:40)

Does this have anything to do with it?


Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently it had something to do with the OPTIONS-preflight not being handled right in the server back-end.

I have implemented the OPTIONS method in the REST endpoint:

```
@OPTIONS
public Response options() {
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Keep in mind this is not a very good way of handling the problem because you need to implement this for every endpoint in your API.

But I didn't find a better solution and this works for me.


Cheers!

Comment: This worked for me too and I agree this is not a good solution.